# Calculate current in branch using Thévenin's theorem

Tags: theory, circuit-analysis, thevenin

[image]

E1 = 20 V

E2 = 5 V

R1 = 10 Ω

R2 = 20 Ω

R3 = 10 Ω

R4 = 10 Ω

R5 = 5 Ω

Calculate Ix.

---

It's obvious that the Thévenin's theorem should have been used, but the implementation is a bit confusing for me in this case. So far I even don't know how to find an substitute impedance outside of the branch with Ix.

Comment: You know how to find the Thévenin equivalent circuit of a voltage divider, right? So look for the voltage dividers.

Comment: Do you have to use Thevenin? I'd use nodal analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would split up the circuit using Thévenin. Next step is calculating \$U_{Th1}\$, \$U_{Th2}\$, \$R_{Th1}\$, \$R_{Th2}\$ and drawing the resulting circuit. Then solving \$I_x\$ should be easy.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbrUfU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As a response to your comment: Shuffle the symbols around a bit ... Nothing changed! You can change positions of components in series:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flhFWg.png)</sup>

Comment: R=RTh1+RTh2 and RTh1=(R1*R2)/(R1+R2), RTh2=(R2*R4)/(R2+R4)?

Comment: looks like a solution